# Is there a way to have incorrect password clear out instead of just shaking?

Tags: mac

When I try to login to my Mac and use a wrong password it shakes but it doesn't clear out the password field or provide an "Incorrect password" notification. Plenty of times I looked away and didn't notice the shaking, and when I looked back at the screen it looked like it was just frozen or I forgot to press enter to login. Is there a way to provide a less temporary visual clue that the password I entered was wrong?

Comment: Isn't the fact that you're still staring at the login screen sufficient clue?

Comment: Not for me - my instinctive reaction every time is that I forgot to press enter.

Comment: It really only needs you to be paying attention for an entire two seconds.

Comment: It bothers me most because it's so different from every other login that I use. My phone (android) immediately tells me that the password is incorrect (and blanks it out). Same for my email. etc. I'm aware that I can pay attention for 2 seconds - I posted here in case there's a way to change the annoying behavior